# Insert into table if not exists else update

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a script so that it checks whether there is a duplicate of, say for example a type of car. It would check the make and type of car (volvo 260, volvo) from the database, then if it exists the user is allowed to change the speed etc. of the car. I've got this so far:

```
INSERT INTO cars (id, car_id, car_name, car_make car_speed, car_passengers)
VALUES (1, 1, 'volvo', 'S60', 150, 4)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE car_speed=VALUES(speed);
```

I would also like it to check the car name as well as the car make. Is that possible to do?

Comment: The logic of what should happen when a duplicate insert occurs is not clear to me.

Comment: You have to use **Google** thing, I heard that's useful for problems like theses !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should read [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) thoroughly.

Then, you will realize that your usage of `values()` in the `on duplicate` is completely wrong.

As *Satish Gupta* said, you will need a unique key on columns `car_name` and `car_make` with

```
ALTER TABLE db_name.table_name ADD UNIQUE key_name (car_name, car_make);
```

The correct statement for your problem in question would be

```
INSERT INTO cars (id, car_id, car_name, car_make car_speed, car_passengers)
  VALUES (1, 1, 'volvo', 'S60', 150, 4)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE car_speed = 150;
```

then.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a key with unique `car_make` and `car_name` with that statement

```
ALTER TABLE `db_name`.`table_name` ADD UNIQUE `key_name` (`car_name`, `car_make`);
```

Comment: That would just fulfill the requirement to get `on duplicate key` in action. The insert statement would still not work.

Comment: thanks, @René Hoffmann for correction